# WPF: unique style for each combo box item bound to dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles

A *ComboBox* bound to the *dictionary (of Enum, String)*. Selected value path is dictionary's *Key*.

Is it possible to set individual style for each combo box item in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I use a custom enum called `Cards`, that has constants `Skull`, `Hearts` and others for demonstration purposes. You can simply use your enum type instead.

### Item Container Style Using Data Triggers

You could create an items container style with triggers for each enum value.

```
<Style x:Key="EnumComboBoxItemStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key}" Value="{x:Static local:Cards.Skull}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key}" Value="{x:Static local:Cards.Hearts}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```
<ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource EnumComboBoxItemStyle}" ...>
```

### Item Container Style Selector

Another option is to create a [style selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.styleselector?view=net-5.0) if you have multiple distinct styles like this:

```
<Style x:Key="SkullComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="HeartsComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<!-- ...other styles. -->
```

The style selector determines the style based on the enum value.

```
public class CardsKeyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
   public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (container is FrameworkElement element && item is KeyValuePair<Cards, string> keyValuePair)
      {
         switch (keyValuePair.Key)
         {
            case Cards.Skull:
               return element.FindResource("SkullComboBoxItemStyle") as Style;
            case Cards.Hearts:
               return element.FindResource("HeartsComboBoxItemStyle") as Style;
            // ...other cases.
         }
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

You can assign the style selector to your combo box and it will choose the right style.

```
<ComboBox ...>
   <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
      <local:CardsKeyStyleSelector/>
   </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Okay, thank You! I've found the solution too through using of ItemTemplate with style with triggers. No code behind needed but dictionary and enumeration only.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is further. First, define enumerable type and dictionary, associated with it:

```
Public Enum MyEnum As Integer
    OneValue = 0
    OtherValue = 1
End Enum

Public ReadOnly Property MyDict As Dictionary(Of MyEnum, String)
    Get
        Return New Dictionary(Of MyEnum, String) From {
            {MyEnum.OneValue, "First value text"},
            {MyEnum.OtherValue, "Other value text"}
        }
    End Get
End Property
```

Next, in XAML use it in this manner:

```
<Style TargetType="Ellipse" x:Key="ellipseStyle">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
    <Style.Triggers>            
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key}" Value="0"><!-- "0" - one of the dictionary key -->
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>          
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Key}" Value="1"><!-- "1" - one of the dictionary key -->
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="cmb_osn_rez">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyDict}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Key" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsControl.ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource ellipseStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```